# 2013 - Left nav flyouts don't show for some users

Tags: navigation, master-page, item-styles

Quick and hopefully easy question: On a 2013 site I have flyouts configured for the left-hand nav menu. For some new users I just added, the code I changed in the masterpage to produce the flyouts (the static and dynamic variables in the menu container) isn't running when they view the site. I gave them full permissions and made sure they weren't restricted in any way from any library (specifically the style library) but the flyouts still will not apply. They simply see the menu laid out normally as if the masterpage were unmodified. The behavior is consistent across browsers and computers. Is something blocking it at runtime? There are very few changes made to this site which is a "Document Center" template.

Edit: As requested, here is the code. It's pretty straight-forward, just changing the static and dynamic display levels.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AspMenu
id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"
runat="server"
EnableViewState="false" 
DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap"
UseSimpleRendering="true"
Orientation="Vertical"
StaticDisplayLevels="1"
AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
SkipLinkText=""
/>-->
```

Originally found the method [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/11b0b939-c647-4389-b81a-5c0b1a8e3c8c/flyout-menu-background). Though I never managed to get the menu width to work like that guy did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After editing the master you did the check in publishing the major version?

Comment: Bingo. I had it checked in and published as a **minor** version. Checked it out and back in as a major version and it worked. The minor version option still calls it "publishing" so I assumed that was good enough, apparently not for a master page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post that modified code in your master page?
I faced that problem in my last project and it was due to screen resolution for some users and browser zoom

Comment: Done, please see above. In this case screen resolution and browser zoom can't have anything to do with it because it works perfectly for one user account, and in the exact same browser window I sign out and back in with another account (one of the new ones) and it's broken. Zero changes in the environment, only the user account itself.